# app/assets/stylesheets配下のディレクトリ構造とファイルの中身の一般的な形は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails4です。

`app/assets/stylesheets`配下のディレクトリ構造とファイルの中身
はどのようにするのが一般的なのでしょうか？

### 例えばコントローラ毎にディレクトリを作る？

コントローラごとにディレクトリを作って、メソッド名ごとのファイルでしょうか？

### 例えばコントローラ毎にコントローラ.css.scssを作る？

コントローラ毎にファイルを作った場合、indexメソッドでは使うけど、editでは使わないCSSも混じってしまうように思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「管理のしやすさ」が場合によると思いますが、
以下の記事が参考になると思います。

http://tech.recruit-mp.co.jp/front-end/web-frontend-dev-lookback/

私の場合、現時点では、

- common：共通部分（レイアウトなど）
- modules：formやbuttonなどの単位で管理
- views：ページ固有のものが出てきた場合（bodyタグにidかclassを付与して、それを親として囲む）
- custom：外部ライブラリ（bower）などのカスタム

という感じで分けてます。デザインをいちから作るケースならmixinsやinheritsで上記記事のように分けていいかもしれません。

javascriptに関しては、以下の様なものを使うと管理しやすいかもしれません。

- [kbparagua/paloma · GitHub](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma)

後は、以下のオープンソースなどで自分にしっくりくる管理形式を参考にしてみては如何でしょうか。

- http://www.opensourcerails.com